# Implement Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: r, classification, linear-discriminant

I try to implement LDA from scratch using this notes https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats202/content/lec9.pdf (page 34)

To check my implementation, I compare my priors, group means, and coefficients of linear discriminants with `lda()` function in MASS library. My priors and group means match with values produced by `lda()`. However, my coefficients differ. Here is the toy example:

```
group1 = replicate(3, rnorm(10, mean = 1))
group2 = replicate(3, rnorm(15, mean = 2)) 
x = rbind(group1, group2)
colnames(x) = c(1, 2, 3)
y = matrix(rep(1, 10), ncol = 1)
y = rbind(y, matrix(rep(2, 15), ncol = 1))
colnames(y) = 'y'

library(MASS)
xy = cbind(x, y)
lda.fit = lda(y ~ ., as.data.frame(xy))

LDA <- function(x, y) {
    group1_index = which( y == 1 )
    group2_index = which( y == 2 )
    #priors:
    prior_group1 = length(group1_index) / length(y)
    prior_group2 = length(group2_index) / length(y)
    print("Prior probabilities of groups:")
    print(c(prior_group1, prior_group2))
    #means:
    mean_group1 = colMeans(x[group1_index, ])
    mean_group2 = colMeans(x[group2_index, ])
    print("Group means:")
    print(rbind(mean_group1, mean_group2))
    #discriminant coefficients:
    x[group1_index, ] = sweep(x[group1_index, ], 2, mean_group1, "-")
    x[group2_index, ] = sweep(x[group2_index, ], 2, mean_group2, "-")
    sigma = solve(cov(x))
    disc_coeff = sigma %*% mean_group1 
    print("Coefficients of linear discriminants:")
    print(disc_coeff)
}

LDA(x, y)
```

So, I compute the vectors of deviations and estimate the covariance matrix as described in slides. Here are the outputs of my implementation and `lda()`:

```
> LDA(x, y)
[1] "Prior probabilities of groups:"
[1] 0.4 0.6

[1] "Group means:"
                    1         2        3
mean_group1 0.9886488 0.7906502 1.228568
mean_group2 1.9180531 1.9603046 2.175800

[1] "Coefficients of linear discriminants:"
      [,1]
1 2.449038
2 2.687901
3 3.108110

> lda.fit
Call:
lda(y ~ ., data = as.data.frame(xy))

Prior probabilities of groups:
  1   2 
0.4 0.6 

Group means:
        `1`       `2`      `3`
1 0.9886488 0.7906502 1.228568
2 1.9180531 1.9603046 2.175800

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
          LD1
`1` 0.7204303
`2` 1.0612863
`3` 1.0114053
```

I tried to look at the source code of `lda()` function, however, it is very complicated for a novice R programmer.

Could anyone please suggest if coefficients of linear discriminants should be computed in a different way? Or probably, `lda()` makes some postprocessing which I did not incorporate in my implementation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding more of your code and a small example showing the differences between your code and lda()